# Is it possible to access Active Directory via LDAP API?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adsi

I am a newbie and I found that I can access Active Directory via ADSI from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746483(v=vs.85).aspx
I also found there is another API called LDAP API to access service provided by LDAP from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367008(v=vs.85).aspx. Is it possible to access Active Directory via this LDAP API and retrieve information about users in AD ?

Comment: In short Yes. You can do it with JNDI, jLDAP and numerous other java LDAP client implementations.

Comment: @ShaMan-H_Fel : More elaborate on my question, is it possible to access AD via LDAP api in C/C++ ?

Comment: Yes it is. You should check http://www.openldap.org/. There should be other libraries for that, but I only used java for accessing AD via LDAP, so I don't know them.

Comment: I have tried openldapv2.4.35 and novell-cldap-devel packages and they pose errors. Including them in the execution results either in undefined reference errors towards ldap operations or some file not found error. :(

Comment: I would suggest to ask another question, complete with details about the errors and sample code. This one is too general, and you will probably not get the answers you need. Also, you should give information on what is the version of AD you are using.